# I get error 404 in Identity Server 4 with .NET Core 8

Tags: c#, identityserver4, .net-8.0, asp.net-core-8

```
using IdentityServer4;
using IdentityServerHost.Quickstart.UI;
using SecurityWebApp.TokenService;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
               .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
               .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIndentityResources())
               .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
               .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    options.ClientId = "----";
    options.ClientSecret = "---";
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


var app = builder.Build();


app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseIdentityServer();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

I was going according to a tutorial, which used .NET Core 2 in the tutorial.

In the training, he wanted to use Identity Server 4, I progressed according to the training, but it did not work.

Please guide me

Thankful